# How hibernate ensures session cache or first level cache is updated with latest data in database?

Tags: hibernate

Suppose 1st time you have retrieve data in hibernate then it will store data in session cache. When 2nd time you will try to access same data then it will take data from cache and give you but on that time any other process has changed data then how will hibernate know that cache data is old data?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not do any cache synchronization with the database.
This is your job.

If the database in the cache can change by another process you make sure that the cache is refreshed.

Comment: Hi Simon, i got your point. But is there any way where if data change in db we can inform to hibernate?

Comment: No but if your database supports something like a change event you could try to trigger an url in your application. But this doesn't have to do with Hibernate.